# Dynamic edition of list items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I display a list of elements using the ng-repeat directive. Each element is displayed within a dedicated div block. I would like to allow block edition meaning that when clicking on an edit button, the content of a element div becomes a form that can be submitted...

I would like to follow the Angularjs philosophy meaning no dom manipulation in controller but rather use directives... ;-)

Comment: writing complete code is not possible please let us know what u have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to conditionally display the elements - either as read only or as a form. It would look something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div ng-hide="editMode(item.id)">
        <!-- This will contain the DOM elements that
             will only display the item -->
        <span>item.text</span>
        <button type="button" ng-click="changeToEditMode(item.id)">
            Edit
        </button>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="editMode(item.id)">
        <!-- This will contain DOM elements that will
             allow editing the item -->
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.text">
        <button type="button" ng-click="editItem(item)">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your controller, you can have the following code:

```
//The list of elements
//Id is needed to uniquely identify an item in the list
$scope.list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "item_1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "item_2"
    }
];

//Contains the ID of the item currently being edited
//You can have single item that can be in edit mode at one time or
//you can have multiple items open in edit mode. Go with an array for the latter
//By default, no item is in edit mode
$scope.itemIdForEdit = 0;

//Checks if the item is in edit mode
$scope.editMode = function (itemId) {
    return $scope.itemForEdit === itemId;
};

//Changes the item being edited
$scope.changeToEditMode = function (itemId) {
    $scope.itemForEdit = itemId;
};

//Edits the item
$scope.editItem = function (item) {
    //Logic to update the item in the $scope.list or backend.
};
```

This way, you can achieve the display and edit of the elements in your list. Note that assigning the model to the input tag already changes the item contents (one feature of AngularJS that I just love - the model is updated automatically, no need to have an explicit Update or Save) - I have provided it for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So you need to hide / show div blocks... Adding and removing blocks in the DOM isn't a solution to consider?

Comment: You could add and remove too. Check out `ng-switch` directive which can be found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch)